# Rails has_many: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a relationship defined where an order has many order items:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
    belongs_to :order
end
```

The orders and order items get stored correctly and with their relationships.

I am trying to display a record of all orders. For that I need to access some attributes from order items, like amount or price.

I defined the following method to calculate the total price of the order, and it is defined in the `Order` model:

```
def total
    order_items.inject(0) { |sum, n| n.price * n.amount + sum }
end
```

I tracked the error and I found out that I am getting the error in this method, this is the error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method`*' for nil:NilClass):`

Is is called from the view, to display the total price of the order.

Actually if I add some line in this method where I try to access any order item attribute, say `order_items[0].price` I am inmediatly getting an error.

I do not get why this is happening.

I have the exact same relationship defined as `ShoppingCart` and `ShoppingCartItems` and did not face this problem.

Also, the order and order items classes I am developing are very similar to a previous project I did with Rails 3.2.9, and it worked fine.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `OrderItem` that doesn't have a `price` or `amount` value.

To verify which `OrderItem` entries don't have a price, do `OrderItem.where(price: nil)`; and for amount do `OrderItem.where(amount: nil)`

To consider these `nil` prices/amounts as 0, change your code to the following:

```
def total
  order_items.map{ |oi| (oi.price || 0) * (oi.amount || 0) }.sum
end
```

Comment: AFAIK, `a * b` is roughly equivalent to `a.*(b)`, that implies that `price` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from this tidbit:

```
n.price * n.amount
```

Ruby is trying to call the `*` method on `n.price`, but `n.price` is returning `nil`, and `nil` does not have a `*` method defined on it, so it blows up with "undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass"

In short, it can't multiply nil, it can normally only do that with number-like or string-like values.

If you want to prevent order items from having nil prices, you can add a model validation:

```
class OrderItem
  validates_numericality_of :price, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
```

Or you can change your calculation method to coerce to safe values:

```
order_items.inject(0) { |sum, n| (n.price || 0) * (n.amount || 1) + sum }
```